# How to stop line from changing length when switching between computers

Tags: vb6

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop with VB6 loaded on that I use to control my model railroad.  See image 121723 working:

[image]

My railroad is located in my garage.  But I program in my house in my den.  I have desktop computers running Windows 11.  When I open the .VBP file, the lines used to indicate the layout track have grown.  See image 010424 working:

[image]

I have ensured the monitor resolution is set to the laptop since this is where the VB6 project file will be running once completed.  The desktop computer monitors are running the same resolution.  I have tried changing the Scale from 100% to 175% but no luck.  Lines have all grown in size but none of the other objects have?

Below is how I changed the line colors.  `BLOCKTABLE` array contains how many lines make up the 33 different blocks.

The user clicking on one of the block letters A to GG uses the index value to the block letter to determine which lines to change the color of.

```
    For I = 0 To BLOCKTABLE(IndexValLookUpLetter, 2)
    If Val(TrainRouteArray(IndexValLookUpLetter, 4)) = OCC Then
        TrainLocation.Blockline((IndexValLookUpLetter * 100) + I).BorderColor = vbRed
        TrainLocation.Blockline((IndexValLookUpLetter * 100) + I).BorderWidth = 2
    ElseIf Val(TrainRouteArray(IndexValLookUpLetter, 4)) = ACT Then
        TrainLocation.Blockline((IndexValLookUpLetter * 100) + I).BorderColor = vbYellow
        TrainLocation.Blockline((IndexValLookUpLetter * 100) + I).BorderWidth = 2
    ElseIf Val(TrainRouteArray(IndexValLookUpLetter, 4)) = PEN Then
        TrainLocation.Blockline((IndexValLookUpLetter * 100) + I).BorderColor = vbGreen
        TrainLocation.Blockline((IndexValLookUpLetter * 100) + I).BorderWidth = 2
    Else
        TrainLocation.Blockline((IndexValLookUpLetter * 100) + I).BorderColor = vbBlack
        TrainLocation.Blockline((IndexValLookUpLetter * 100) + I).BorderWidth = 1
    End If
Next I
```

I don't believe this is a coding issue rather than a possible hardware issue.  I don't know and that is why I'm asking.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You haven't provided any images but in any case you'll have to provide some more information of how you're using Vb6 and the code you're using to create the lines before we can even guess what's happening.

Comment: John, the lines are in an Array named BlockLine with an Index starting at 100.  So if a BlockLine A has 5 line segments, the Index is 100 to 104 to make changing the color of the lines from Black, to Green, to Yellow to Red.

Comment: John, I don't believe this is a coding issue but rather a settings issue with VB6 or Windows.  I just can't believe anyone else is having this issue.

Comment: There are other anomalies as well.  For example, the big, blank white rectangle in the lower left is not in the same location.  Are you dynamically laying out the screen?

Comment: Brian, I just moved the list object because they can grow depending on the items in the list.  Just trying to make the form look better.  I may have moved these up while working on my laptop at my daughter's house.

Comment: Brain,      Begin VB.ListBox lstTrainRoute 
      Appearance      =   0  'Flat
      Height          =   3150
      ItemData        =   "TrainLocation.frx":0000
      Left            =   2280
      List            =   "TrainLocation.frx":0002
      TabIndex        =   202
      Top             =   6360
      Width           =   4095
   End
   Begin VB.ListBox lstSelectedTrainRoute 
      Appearance      =   0  'Flat
      Height          =   225
      Left            =   2280
      TabIndex        =   201
      Top             =   5490
      Width           =   4695
   End

Comment: Brain, I have looked at the objects and they have similar coding in the .frm file that states.     Begin VB.ListBox lstTrainRoute <> Appearance = 0<>Height=3150<>Left= 2280<>TabIndex=202<>Top=6360<>Width=4095<> End then comes the next Begin.  Is this what you mean by dynamically???  I only use code to change the color of the lines.  Will hard coding the Line (X1, X2, Y1, Y2) solve this issue?

Comment: The form ScaleMode is set to 3 'Pixel

Comment: You don't have any VB code where you specify the location of the objects?  That's what I mean by dynamically.  If not,  then every object on the screen is drawn visually using the VB6 form designer.  I have never experienced what you are seeing using the designer, but I also only work on a single desktop.

Comment: I notice two possibly significant items - the projects in the two images are **not** the same code/project.  Desktop image project has frmRouteSelect.frm that the laptop image project does not. And the frm declarations in the comments for lstTrainRoute are different (second one does not have saved list items in an frx file). So I think you could be trying to compare apples to oranges. I suggest you update the project(s) so that they are the same and then test and compare.

Comment: I agree with Brian. I've never seen a problem like that and I used to switch reguarly between coding on a Windows 7 and Windows 10 machine. However both had the same size and resolution monitors.

Comment: You are definitely using two different sets of code though. You only have to look at the window header title on the two machines to tell that they're different! I assumed that you were using the exact same code and frm files on both machines but that's obviously not the case.

Comment: Everyone, I changed my Screen scale to 175% and everything is where it is supposed to be.  What am I changing by screen scale of 175%?

Comment: OH, I forgot to say I changed the form mode to Twips vice Pixels.

Comment: As I said in my last comment you're using two different frm files on the two PCs. One has the TrainLocation.Caption as "TrainLocationB" and the other as "Martin's MMR Layout" so the first thing to do is make sure that both PCs have identical source files on them and then see if they both behave the same.

Comment: What method do you use to share code between different computers?

Comment: Just a thumbdrive StayOnTarget.  I did figure my problem out.  I changed the form ScaleMode back to Twips and the lines are now in the correct position.  Don't know why but I want to thank everyone for their time and effort in finding a solution to my problem.

Comment: Neat looking application, @MartinCox!